# Fabric executing command on remote server doesn't work

Tags: python, fabric

I want use fabric in python, to execute command on remote server.

I wrote these:

```
from fabric.api import *
from fabric.tasks import execute
def do_some_thing():
    run("ls -lh")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    execute(do_some_thing,hosts=['root@10.18.103.102'])
```

but, it doesn't work and make me login..

It's the output:

```
➜  ~  python test.py
[root@10.18.103.102] Executing task 'do_some_thing'
[root@10.18.103.102] run: ls -lh
[root@10.18.103.102] out: root@svn:~#
[root@10.18.103.102] out: root@svn:~#
```

Answer (score 2):

Make use of the `env` variable -

```
from fabric.api import *
from fabric.contrib.files import *

def myserver():
    env.hosts = ['10.18.103.102']
    env.user = 'root'
    # if you have key based authentication, uncomment and point to private key
    # env.key_filename = '~/.ssh/id_rsa'
    # if you have password based authentication
    env.password = 'ThEpAsAwOrd'

def ls():
    run('ls -al')
```

Now save these in a file call `fabfile.py` and execute (on the same directory) -

```
$ fab myserver ls
```

Fabric will execute both the functions one after another. So when it executes `ls()` it'll have the server details in `env`.

Comment: Thank you. I want to use fabric as lib in python without 'fab' command ,how should I do?

Comment: Call both function upon execution. That should do it.